# how to extract web page textual content in java?

Tags: java

i am looking for a method to extract text from web page (initially html) using  jdk or another library .   please help

thanks

Comment: Best Way is using        "compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a [HTML parser](http://www.google.co.id/search?q=Java+HTML+parser) if at all possible; there are many available for Java.

Or you can use regex like many people do. This is generally not advisable, however, unless you're doing very simplistic processing.

#### Related questions

- [Java HTML Parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238036/java-html-parsing)
- [Which Html Parser is best?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168610/which-html-parser-is-best)
- [Any good Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806131/any-good-java-html-parsers)
- [recommendations for a java HTML parser/editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/709233/recommendations-for-a-java-html-parser-editor)
- [What HTML parsing libraries do you recommend in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26638/what-html-parsing-libraries-do-you-recommend-in-java)

Text extraction:

- [Text Extraction from HTML Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386107/text-extraction-from-html-java)
- [Text extraction with java html parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609948/text-extraction-with-java-html-parsers)

Tag stripping:

- [Stripping HTML tags in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832620/stripping-html-tags-in-java)
- [How to strip HTML attributes except “src” and “alt” in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560605/how-to-strip-html-attributes-except-src-and-alt-in-java)
- [Removing HTML from a Java String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240546/removing-html-from-a-java-string)

Answer (score 14):

Use [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/). This is currently the most elegant library for screen scraping.

```
URL url = new URL("http://example.com/");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3*1000);
String title = doc.title();
```

I just love its [CSS selector syntax](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax).

Comment: Love jsoup but it doesn't execute associated Javascript. For Javascript rendered pages I use Selenium.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a short method that nicely wraps these details (based on `java.util.Scanner`):

```
public static String get(String url) throws Exception {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(Scanner sc = new Scanner(new URL(url).openStream()); sc.hasNext(); )
      sb.append(sc.nextLine()).append('\n');
   return sb.toString();
}
```

And this is how it is used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   System.out.println(get("http://www.yahoo.com"));
}
```