# Load a website without webview?

Tags: android, web-applications, web

At first: this is my first post here, so please tell me if I did something wrong :)

So... I wanted to ask how I could load a website without a webview.
I'm trying to make an app that makes it easier to play a specific browser-game

My idea was to load the website and let my app show an activity based on the content of this loaded site. The app basically shows no WebViews. Or can I make the WebView invisible somehow?

As you might have already realized, I'm not that advanced with android/java programming. (although I'm not that bad at HTML/CSS and really basic C++) So please try to keep the codes short.

Thank you :)

Comment: It's not totally clear what you're asking. If you want to pick out data from a web page you could always parse the page and use normal Android view stuff to show that data.

Comment: I want to load/send the data from and to the server. Just like a webview/browser does. For example: I load this page (my post here) to my app, and the HTML code says that this post has the tag "android", so my activity shows a button that says "android"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly then you can try HTML parser. The HTML page will be parsed by using java and you can extract the website's content without loading/display the actual web page. You might need to use firebug or chrome dev tool to see which part of the web page that you want to extract. HTML parser can be found here:
[HTML parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036638/how-to-extract-web-page-textual-content-in-java)

Comment: It just said that I needed to wait 3 more minutes ;)

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) . it can parse html websites just fine .

Answer (score 0):

The WebView and Chromium are just an extension of Google Data-Saver proxy.
  There is no way to get around the proxy.  Google has blocked all other web views.  
If you want to create an app that can connect to a website without the Data-Saver proxy you will need to build and compile a 3rd party browser, then create a custom browser app for Android such as Firefox or Opera has done. 
 If you want your WebView hacked to go though a different proxy you can upload your finished .apk file to [here](https://developer.huawei.com/en/) where the Chinese government will simulate Google's proxy when they distribute your app through Huawei's App Gallery.  
It does work better without Google's Data-Saver even if the .apk is the same on both stores.